# C: character comparison fails

Tags: c, entab-detab

After succesfully running an entabulator, my detabulator won't pick up on a character comparison that should exit a while loop. After trying "0(tab)8(enter)(ctrl+D)" as input the tab is written correctly as spaces, but after rp is incremented to point to the 8, the while loop that should read the 8 won't exit and I get a seg fault. Here's the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 100
char doc[9001];
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int max = 0;
    char *rp = doc;
    char *wp = rp;
    char *tf = wp;
    char *lp = doc;

    while ((*(rp++) = getchar()) != EOF);
    *--rp = '\0';
    rp = doc;
    j = 0;
    while  ( (*rp != '\0') && (argc == 1)) {
        if (*rp == '\n') {
            lp = rp + 1;
            *wp++ = *rp++;
        }

        while( (*rp != '\t') && (*rp != '\0') && (*rp != '\n') ) { /*this loops after a tab*/
            *wp++ = *rp++;
        }
        if (*rp == '\t') {
            rp++;
            tf = lp + ((((wp - lp) / 8) + 1) * 8);
            while ((tf - wp) != 0) 
                *wp++ = 's';
        }
    }
    if (*rp == '\0')    
        *wp = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", doc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I feel is, the below loop is going into infinite loop.

```
while( (*rp != '\t') && (*rp != '\0') && (*rp != '\n') ) { /*this loops after a tab*/
    *wp++ = *rp++;
```

This is because, you are checking for `rp!= '\t'` and so on, but here

```
if (*rp == '\t') 
{
    rp++;
    tf = lp + ((((wp - lp) / 8) + 1) * 8);
    while ((tf - wp) != 0) 
        *wp++ = 's';
}
```

you are filling the `doc` array with char `'s'` and which is over writing `'\t'` also, so the above loop is going to infinite.

Comment: You're right, I can't read the input because I've overwritten it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some as yet unexplored problems with the initial input loop.

You should never risk overflowing a buffer, even if you allocate 9001 bytes for it.  That's how viruses and things break into programs.  Also, you have a problem because you are comparing a character with EOF.  Unfortunately, `getchar()` returns an `int`: it has to because it returns any valid character value as a positive value, and EOF as a negative value (usually -1, but nothing guarantees that value).

So, you might write that loop more safely, and clearly, as:

```
char *end = doc + sizeof(doc) - 1;
int c;

while (rp < end && (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    *rp++ = c;
*rp = '\0';
```

With your loop as written, one of two undesirable things happens:

- if `char` is an unsigned type, then you will never detect EOF.
- if `char` is a signed type, then you will detect EOF when you read a valid character (often ÿ, y-umlaut, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS, U+00FF).

Neither is good.  The code above avoids both problems without needing to know whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned.

Conventionally, if you have an empty loop body, you emphasize this by placing the semicolon on a line on its own.  Many an infinite loop has been caused by a stray semicolon after a `while` condition; by placing the semicolon on the next line, you emphasize that it is intentional, not accidental.

```
while ((*(rp++) = getchar()) != EOF);
```

```
while ((*(rp++) = getchar()) != EOF)
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me these places where the code would fail. Clearly I need to keep in mind portability and security issues.